# Sync Atom.io settings across OS

Tags: configuration, ide, preferences, atom-editor

I am running Windows 10 and OSx in a home-office setup and would like to sync my preferences and configs for Atom IDE between them.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source project on github [sync-settings](https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings) that does exactly this *(found it on google)*